# How can I create a global alert?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

In LEX I'm trying to figure out my capabilities to give various notifications to the users. I've played with toasts, that works well.  Notifications (fancy alert boxes) look simple thought I haven't played with those.  The LDS docs list [several other notification tools](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/overview/).  One of which is [alerts](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/components/alerts/).

Clicking through the alerts docs, I found some [sample code](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/alert/).  However if I paste that in a lightning component it unsurprisingly looks nothing like what the alert is supposed to look like (a banner across the top of the window).

Are the other tools (outside of Toasts and Notifications) mentioned in my first link available for us to use or is that just what the system UI does?

Comment: Are you trying to create an alert regardless of the page a user is on in Salesforce?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I haven't come across any UI component that lets us modify a horizontal bar stretching across the screen. I keep close tabs on `lightning:overlayLibrary` and my gut feeling is that library will be augmented with more methods in the future to include stuff like the alerts you've found in SLDS.

Comment: When you say a 'global' alert, do you mean a message all the way on the top of the page (above lightning page header)? On a side note, other types of notifications which I believe you didn't already cover could be: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/

Comment: The requirement I have is a little vague.  Request is to notify a subset or perhaps all users of things like new policies, system downtime, etc.  My thought was to put a component on the home page which slaps an alert banner at the top of the page.

Having it run from any page as @DanielHoechst suggests would be even better.

Comment: You can't display it on any page, unfortunately. I'd also say `lightning:overlayLibrary` is the thing to look at.